# Dockerfile in .gitlab-ci getting stuck on maven downloading dependencies

Tags: docker, maven-3, gitlab

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
this is my extremely simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 as build
COPY src/ /usr/src/myapp/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/myapp
RUN mvn -X -f /usr/src/myapp/pom.xml package


FROM tomcat:9.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/myapp/target/untitled1-1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
EXPOSE 8080
```

I tried a couple of projects same result the pipeline will build mvn and move to the docker build and gets stuck on different parts of downloading from central eventually timeuting

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:19.03.15-dind

variables:
  #DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

stages:
  - build
  - package

maven-build:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  stage: build
  script: "mvn package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.war

docker-build:
  stage: package
  script:
   - docker info
   - docker build -t registry:4567/root/sample .
   - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry:4567
   - docker push registry:4567/root/sample
```

Tried different images it all ends up stuck on the downloading inside docker, not sure from where to tackle this.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found two solututions to the problem, either use the gitlab application install gitlab-runner or install the gitlab runner with helm chart and creating a secret from the .crt from the /etc/gitlab/ssl helped at the next step :)